# Python merge insert duplicate column values instead of creating _x & _y columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have 2 data sets:

Data A:

```
Column A  Column B  Column C    
Hello      NaN      John    
Bye        NaN      Mike
```

Data B:

```
Column A  Column B    
Hello      123
```

Raw data:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([['Hello', np.nan,'John'],['Bye',np.nan,'Mike']], columns=['Column A','Column B','Column C'])
b = pd.DataFrame([['Hello', 123]], columns=['Column A','Column B'])
```

I want to merge Data A & B using left join (as Data A should be the main data and only bring in if they have matching Column A on Data B), and want to bring in Data B's Column B's numeric onto Data A's Column B.

The columns match but my script below results in two Column B's.

```
df=a.merge(b, on ='Column A', how='left')
```

df:

```
Column A  Column B_x  Column C  Column B_y
Hello      NaN        John       123
Bye        NaN        Mike
```

I want the following result:

```
Column A  Column B  Column C
Hello       123      John
Bye         NaN      Mike
```

Please note I need to effectively insert Column B's data correlating to Column A, not just push Data B into Data A in exact row order. I need the code to find the match for Column A regardless of which row it's located in and insert them appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `merge` for this as a merge will bring the columns of the two dataframes together. Since your dataframes follow the same structure, `fillna` or `update`:

```
a.fillna(b, inplace = True) # not in place unless you specify inplace=True 
a.update(b) # modifies NA in place using non-NA values from another DataFrame
```

---

```
print(a)

  Column A  Column B Column C
0    Hello     123.0     John
1      Bye       NaN     Mike
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be working. Let me test a few more times and I'll select you as the answer. It does look like a.update(b) works and not a.fillna(b), however.

Comment: Welcome. Maybe ```a.fillna(b)``` is working, it's just not modifying your dataframe. So can you try changing it to ```new_a = a.fillna(b)```, or ```a.fillna(b, inplace = True)``` ?

Comment: Have you tried it? @LEOMODE

Comment: Sorry but this still didn't fix the problem, because when I merge it with a different column, it just merges without actually matching the same rows. So if I have multiple lines of various numbers that do not necessarily correlate to each line of rows, all your code does is just insert Data B into the original order. So say if I have 10 lines and 123 should go into 5 axis, because 123 was in axis 0 it just merges on axis 0. Both codes you suggested do the same as below guy. @sophocles

Comment: Hi @LEOMODE. My answer works perfectly with the sample data you have provided above, I just re-tested it and I can confirm it. Can you please try to update it with your issue and I will try to solve? Try to update your sample data enough (i.e. to a point that I can recreate the issue you are running into) and ask clearly what exactly is you're trying to get to. Please do that and i will do my best to help